# Tell if a system of vectors is a basis based upon the pivots...

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been asked to determine whether or not a set of three vectors is a basis. I understand that I should build a matrix with these vectors as columns, put into an echelon form and analyze the pivots. If I were dealing with a matrix with real entries, I'd have no problem completing the task. However, I was given the $3$ vectors

$$ \begin{align}
a_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\-i \end{pmatrix}, \\ 
a_2 &= \begin{pmatrix} i+1 & i-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \\
a_3 &= \begin{pmatrix} i \\ i \\ i \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}$$

I was then asked to determine whether the system of vectors was a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$.

To answer, I constructed the $3 \times3$ matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \end{pmatrix}$, put into an echelon form, and considered the pivots. The echelon form I got showed a pivot in every row $\Rightarrow$ generating, and a pivot in every column $\Rightarrow$ uniqueness. From this, I came to the conclusion that they were indeed a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$.

**Question**

I know this logic is certainly valid for a system of vectors composed with real numbers while considering a real space. Is the same true for this particular question?

I can think of no reason for this to be any different. I see no way for an inconsistency to exist since the scalars are complex.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Summarizing : If an echelon form of a complex matrix has a pivot in every column, and a pivot in every row, does this imply that the columns of the matrix are a basis for the target space?

Comment: If you can get the matrix into upper triangular form where there are no zeros on the diagonal, you have a basis.

Comment: You can also compute the determinant (the same way than with real matrices). I personnally prefer that to pivots (although you often end up doing the same thing).